# HomePod no longer responds to Siri

Tags: performance, siri, homepod

HomePod does not respond to my Siri commands anymore. I have tried to reset HomePod.

Answer (score 1):

In the Home app on your iOS or iPadOS device, touch and hold a HomePod.

Scroll down, tap the Settings button, then do any of the following:

- Enable “Hey Siri” requests: Turn on Listen for “Hey Siri.”
- Enable summoning Siri using HomePod touch controls: Turn on Touch and
  Hold for Siri.
- Enable indicator light when Siri is listening: Turn on Light When
  Using Siri.
- Hear a chime when Siri is listening: Turn on Sound When Using Siri.

Source: https://support.apple.com/guide/homepod/change-settings-apde6dc8093d/homepod

Comment: I like the detail here, but wouldn’t my reset procedure do the same thing? You may be correct that since the person says “anymore”, they didn’t realize they turned it off.

Comment: Correct its likely because they forgot about turning it off.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not reset the device to factory settings, the next step would be to arrange service with Apple.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208244